# Wordpress Multi Site Image Issue

Tags: image, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm running a WP 3.5.1 multisite install and the images on my site suddenly stopped showing up; I think I've traced it to a .htaccess issue but now I'm stuck.

Using the default .htaccess code displays only broken images on my site:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

... but if I replace the RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L] line with this, it ALMOST works; regular images show up fine, but timthumb-returned files (using the same image URL) DON'T work:

`RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-content/blogs.dir/3/files/$2 [L]`

... the only trouble is, my theme uses timthumb pretty extensively and it's still showing broken images through timthumb and I don't particularly want to edit the .htaccess file for every site I maintain.  How can I fix this?

Comment: I use the .htaccess found in the codex.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration

Is it theme specific? I was working with a theme that wasn't multisite friendly, I found this writeup on how to modify timthumb.php to work with multisite:
http://wpcodesnippets.info/blog/how-to-use-timthumb-php-with-multisites.html

Note: the solution above was for a theme that didn't have /blogs.dir/ in mind and passed incorrect paths to timthumb.php and broke it. Hope this helps.

Comment: I had high hopes for that but it didn't work out ... I was already using the new version of timthumb and making the changes didn't work.  The .htaccess code from the codex doesn't work but I'm halfway functional with the revision above.  I did note this on the codex page: Issues with old WPMU installs

If you installed WordPress MU in subfolder/subdirectory ... and you have problem with image library, where thumbnails and images do not show, you may need to manually add in rewrite rules ... as follows:

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?siteN/files/(.+) wp-content/blogs.dir/N/files/$2 [L]

Comment: I have a similar problem over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567450/wordpress-multisite-sub-domain-images-not-appearing-redirect-rules that I am trying to solve.
I tried this solution, even trying /blogs.dir/N/files or specific /blogs.dir/4/files for specific sub blogs, no luck :(